# MySQL add a NOT NULL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am adding a column to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD c varchar(10) NOT NULL;
```

The column gets added, and each record has the empty string.

Is this expected to work this way under all conditions (strict mode, etc.) in MySQL 5.5+?

Comment: yes. Otherwise it'd be impossible to add a new column to a table. New columns will set their value to be the default for that column, or the appropriate "automatic default" value for their type. For a `varchar not null`, that's an empty string.

Comment: @MarcB, that's what I figured. Thank you for verifying.

Comment: @MarcB, as user2864740 said, it would be perfectly possible.  You would just need to specify a default, which other DBMSes require here.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In MySQL, each column type has an ["*implicit default*" value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html).

> For string types [the implicit] default value is the empty string.

If a NOT NULL column is [added to a table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html), and no explicit DEFAULT is specified, the implicit default value is used to populate the new column data<sup>1</sup>. Similar rules apply when the DEFAULT value is specified.

As such, the original DDL produces the same results as:

```
-- After this, data will be the same, but schema has an EXPLICIT DEFAULT
ALTER TABLE t ADD c varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
-- Now we're back to the IMPLICIT DEFAULT (MySQL stores NULL internally)
ALTER TABLE t ALTER c DROP DEFAULT
```

The "strict" mode settings affects DML statements relying on default values, but do not affect the implicit default usage when the column is added.

> For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause, if an *INSERT or REPLACE statement* includes no value for the column [and if] strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs ..

Here is [an sqlfiddle "proof"](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12d8b/1) that strict mode does not apply to the ALTER TABLE .. ADD statement.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a MySQL feature. Other engines, like SQL Server, require an explicit DEFAULT (or NULL column) constraint for such schema changes.

Comment: Note: MariaDB has changed that as well, so that in MariaDB the user has to provide an explicit DEFAULT value for a NOT NULL column.

Comment: Is it necessary to have NOT NULL and DEFAULT together? because with a specified default value, it will never be null.

Comment: @TS yes, if you want to enforce the value is never null. for example, with only a DEFAULT set on the column it would be possible to `INSERT INTO t SET c = NULL` - but with NOT NULL on the column, this statement will fail