# mysql sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES" adding integer column NOT NULL with no default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am adding the following column to a table and I am surprised it doesn't give an error because there is no default value for the column and there is data in the table. When I executed this, the rows with data got a default value of 0 with STRICT_ALL_TABLES.

Is this expected behavior? I couldn't find it documented anywhere.

```
ALTER TABLE phppos_receivings ADD COLUMN location_id INT(11) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL add a NOT NULL column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868345/mysql-add-a-not-null-column)

Comment: This almost answers my question and I am 99% confident in the answer, but the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html doesn't explain "implicit default" value for ALTER statements.

Comment: Yeah, but it does describe the strict behavior only in the context of INSERT/REPLACE/UPDATE. So I assume DDL may behave differently. This is the best I can come up with, so I think it falls into the category of "not documented."