# Why does alter table set blank values to new not null varchar columns without default value specification?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table:

```
| customers | CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  
 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

The table already has two rows:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | John Woo  |
|  3 | Maria Loo |
+----+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am trying to alter the table with the following statement:

```
alter table customers add column (identity varchar(32) not null);
```

I would expect this statement to fail, due to the fact that I do not specify a default value and the table already has some rows. But it does not. Instead, it adds the column and sets `''` as value for that new
column to all existing rows.

```
+----+-----------+----------+
| id | name      | identity |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | John Woo  |          |
|  3 | Maria Loo |          |
+----+-----------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way I can make MySQL behave as I expect? I think there is something that one can set at MySQL server configuration variables. But I am not sure.

Any help?

**Update** Note that strict mode is already ON:

```
mysql> show variables where variable_name like '%mode%';
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                                                                                                         |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ---------------------+
| block_encryption_mode    | aes-128-ecb                                                                                                                                  |
| gtid_mode                | OFF                                                                                                                                       |
| innodb_autoinc_lock_mode | 1                                                                                                                                         |
| innodb_strict_mode       | ON                                                                                                                                        |
| offline_mode             | OFF                                                                                                                                       |
| pseudo_slave_mode        | OFF                                                                                                                                       |
| rbr_exec_mode            | STRICT                                                                                                                                    |
| slave_exec_mode          | STRICT                                                                                                                                    |
| sql_mode                 | ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason appears to be that strict mode is enforced for DML issued to the database. DDL does not go through the DML machinery. Why does it behave this way? Speculation- if the database owner wants a column to be not null, then the database is doing its best to adhere to the owner's intent, which it can do with the implicit defaults feature, if the owner does not provide an explicit default.

See this answer for a reference to a sqlfiddle proof:

[MySQL add a NOT NULL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868345/mysql-add-a-not-null-column/22868473#22868473)

Comment: I have already strict mode enabled. And it does not seem to be working.

Comment: If the table in question is myisam, then the sqlmode is still nonstrict. "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES" only applies to transactional engines. If myisam or non-transactional, try enabling STrIcT_ALL_TABLES.

Comment: As you can see from the output of `show create table` command, the table uses InnoDB and not MYISAM engine. Btw, have you tried my case on your database? Does it work?

Comment: Ok, I see. It looks as though the strict settings only impact DML issued to the database. "alter table add" is DDL that does not go through the DML machinery, so new not null columns will get the implicit or explicit default value for the column type. This answer contains a sqlfiddle proof of same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868345/mysql-add-a-not-null-column/22868473#22868473. I will update the answer.